# open source image filter library like Instagram?

Tags: android, instagram

I am developing an application(android) that want to do some image filter effect like in Instagram, just wondering if there is any open source library available?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can take a look at Androids [Effects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/effect/EffectFactory.html) package. The source of this class is available.

Comment: Hi Kenny, i need to add Image filter on my created bitmap, i don't know how to use Effects package did you please provide some example tutorial other than that developer document

Comment: also its only availabe after api 14.

Comment: this example is good but is there any way to create a custom effect like vintage etc using the same code? Because this code is quiet fast

Comment: Here is a good library for extra filters @VaishaliSharma https://github.com/mordonez-me/instagram-filters-jhlabs-android, not as fast but it works well

Comment: actually this code is using Gradle library, due to which am not able to import this project in eclipse

Answer (score 12):

You can use a library GPU image processing.
use this link https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Answer (score 9):

If you have downloaded API-17 samples for SDK, then refer to HelloEffects code from there. It uses EffectFactory to perform image conversions. Other options you have is to use OpenCV, else get algorithms and use it with NDK.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to look at the image processing part of this tutorial series.
http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/

Also there is a library I found
http://code.google.com/p/android-image-filtering/